# Ladino Story Called "Bread of G-d"

Tags: sources-mekorot, bread

Can anyone find me the source of the story I have heard entitled *Pan de Di-o (Bread of G-d)* in Ladino?  It is about a shamash who puts bread in an aron kodesh and thinks that Hashem is eating his bread.

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 8):

In fact the Blog Daas Torah translated it here is the link

[Strange tale concerning a man of simple but flawed belief & the Arizal](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2010/11/strange-tale-concerning-man-of-simple.html)

Comment: Very hilarious story with a bitter ending.

Answer (score 4):

MORESHET AVOT III, p. 132

Story happened in Tzefas and Arizal was involved.